# foreign key not displaying as null after input

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite

i have created a dabasehelper class with three tables, i want student table primary key to be the foreign key in examResult table. But when i enter data in examResult table it display the foreign key column as null

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"student_and_parent_table1\" ( `ID` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `Name` TEXT, `FatherName` TEXT, `MotherName` TEXT, `ParentEmail` TEXT, `FatherPhoneNumber` INTEGER, `MotherPhoneNumber` INTEGER, `Address` TEXT, `Username` TEXT, `Password` TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query2);


        String query3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"teacher_table1\" ( `ID` integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `Name` TEXT, `Email` TEXT, `MobileNumber` INTEGER, `Username` TEXT, `Password` text, `Address` text, `Qualification` TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(query3);

       String query4 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"exam_table1\" ( `StudentID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `StudentName` TEXT,  `SubjectName` TEXT, `SubjectCode` TEXT, `MaxMarks` INTEGER, `MarksScoredByStudent` INTEGER, `Grade` TEXT, `StudentRegNo` integer, FOREIGN KEY(StudentRegNo) REFERENCES student_and_parent_table1(ID) )";
        db.execSQL(query4);
```

Comment: Where's your insertion code? That's kind of important. Needs a [mcve].

Comment: Also, if you're quoting identifier names (Which isn't needed with any of your table or column names), at least be consistent... don't mix standard SQL double quotes with MySQL style backticks. One or the other - preferably the standard one.

Answer (score 0):

There are two **potential** issues *(due to the limited code provided it is impossible to tell exactly why NULL's are being inserted)*.

## Issue 1 - Foreign Key Support

The first is that by default Foreign Key support is turned off and therefore needs to be turned on. To turn foreign key support on you can override the database helper's **onConfigure** method to call the **SQLiteDatabase**'s **setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled** method e.g.

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onConfigure(db);
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

## Issue 2 - Constraints

The second is a common misunderstanding about what Foreign Keys are.

When you define a Foreign Key you are simply adding a constraint (rule) that says that a value in the child column MUST be a value that exists in the parent column. NULL being an exception/special case that indicates no relation to a parent (unless a NOT NULL constraint is applied to the child column).

A common misunderstanding is that specifying a Foreign Key automatically assigns values, it does not, it only checks that the value being inserted is a valid value, you still have to programatically determine the value to be inserted.

As such you may wish to add a **NOT NULL** constraint to the child (**StudentRegNo**) column, which would enforce the use of a valid value.

e.g. use :-

```
String query4 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \"exam_table1\" ( `StudentID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, `StudentName` TEXT,  `SubjectName` TEXT, `SubjectCode` TEXT, `MaxMarks` INTEGER, `MarksScoredByStudent` INTEGER, `Grade` TEXT, `StudentRegNo` integer NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(StudentRegNo) REFERENCES student_and_parent_table1(ID) )";
```